# What is the context instance prop of react-redux provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was reading about **React-Redux provider** in the library [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) and i faced **'context instance'** prop as one prop for the provider, i couldn't really understand what it means:

`context You may provide a context instance. If you do so, you will need to provide the same context instance to all of your connected components as well. Failure to provide the correct context results in runtime error:`

**Is it the whole store data?? the destination component of data??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is it the whole store data?? the destination component of data??**

No, the `context` props is a [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instance, which allow you using `store` directly in its consumer instead of through `connect`, `useSelector` or `useStore`. As its doc, you can either create your custom context or using redux's `ReactReduxContext`

Comment: so its the react context not redux context, thank you, it is clear now